# How can I bind_rows of two random sets and then plot them as a histogram in dplyr?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm having a hard time binding rows of two random samples of 500 each to get one file with 1000 rows.

Then I'm trying to plot a histogram of this combined sample and `geom_density()`.

For my bind_rows line, the error I get is

> "Argument 1 must have names"

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong? Thank you,

```
x <- 1:500
rand1 <- rnorm(length(x), -1, 0.6)
rand2 <- rnorm(length(x), 1, 1.2)
combined <- bind_rows(rand1, rand2)
ggplot(combined, aes(x=y, y=..density..))  +
  geom_histogram(fill = "red", alpha = 0.5, color="darkred") +
  geom_density()
```

Comment: to append a vector to a vector use c(. , .).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the offending line to:

```
 combined <- data.frame(y= c(rand1, rand2))
```

There were two issues that prevent the original code from completing the task: a) no name for the data argument, and b) lack of packaging in a form that could be coerced to a dataframe. The `combined` could also have been a named list.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to bind your two samples, you need to convert them as dataframe. However, you will also need to have their names matching. 
So something like that should work:

```r
library(dplyr)
combined <- bind_rows(data.frame(x =rand1), 
                      data.frame(x =rand2))

           x
1 -1.1979747
2 -0.7819008
3 -2.0965976
4 -0.4637334
5 -1.4314750
6 -0.4356943
```

However, you can't differentiate `rand1` and `rand2` anymore.

So, an alternative solution is to start by binding your two random samples as columns and then pivot the dataframe into a longer format using `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` package:

```r
df <- data.frame(rand1, rand2)
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "rand", values_to = "value")

   rand   value
   <chr>  <dbl>
 1 rand1 -1.20 
 2 rand2  2.45 
 3 rand1 -0.782
 4 rand2  1.35 
 5 rand1 -2.10 
 6 rand2  1.98 
 7 rand1 -0.464
 8 rand2  0.733
 9 rand1 -1.43 
10 rand2  2.72 
# … with 990 more rows
```

For plotting histogram and density, I used `stat(ndensity)` and `..scaled..` in order to set both random samples to be scaled up to 1:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = value, fill = rand))+
  geom_density(aes(y = ..scaled..), alpha = 0.4)+
  geom_histogram(aes(x = value, stat(ndensity)), color = "black", alpha =0.2)
```

[image]